# How to allow scripts in HTML in CSP

Tags: html, content-security-policy

My script-src for my website continues to produce an error and refuses to load my scripts which lie within my Header.html file, and I have tried multiple websites, including reading the docs, however I am unsure of what I am doing wrong of if I just need to be patient and wait for it to take effect on my site.

I am currently using a Meta tag for my CSP policy,

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

```html
<script src='https://th4rjdmmrjsz.statuspage.io/embed/script.js'></script>
```

However, regardless of what I do with it nothing seems to work, I have used sites like RapidSec and the CSP site itself, including an auto generator, and nothing seems to have worked. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like some middleware already publish default CSP via HTTP header, therefore meta-tag does not work as expected. Could you show examples of errors and clarify which server do you use, node.js?

Comment: I’m not sure how to get the actual code itself, but, the error states resources are blocked from loading due to page settings, then gives me script-src as the main problem, I use express and node to launch my project as a whole

Comment: NodeJS + Express uses [Helmet middleware](https://helmetjs.github.io/#how-it-works), the v4 of it's publushes a default CSP. Use `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)` to set CSP rules or you can disable CSP in Helmet middleware: `app.use( helmet({ contentSecurityPolicy: false, }) );` and after that your meta tag will begin works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSP has versions (or levels) with newly supported features extending the original spec. Serving the CSP through an html meta header is considered legacy and has some drawbacks/bugs. **Try setting CSP via the HTTP headers of the request**.

Also, if you're using RapidSec, you can use the integrations (Wordpress plugin, Node.js package) that do this automatically for you.

Comment: It worked through the Helmet request but still, this would be amazing information to others.

Comment: Yes, helmet sets the http response headers under the hood.